# PyWAVES: simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python-3.x, wavesplatform

```
import pywaves as pw

def main():
    node = "https://nodes.wavesnodes.com"
    chain = "mainnet"

    pw.setNode(node=node, chain=chain)

    private_key = #############
    my_address_statement = pw.Address(privateKey=private_key)
    WAVES_balance = my_address_statement.balance()

    print("Your WAVES balance is: %d." % WAVES_balance)
    main()

main()
```

Eventually this code produces the error indicated in the title. How can this be avoided?

Comment: For which part from the code does it throw this error?
Can you for example do a print(my_address_statement) ?
Also pywaves is default set on a node and on mainnet. So no need to reset it.

It would be good to have some added debug steps/ full error/stack trace

Comment: It looks like removing 
```node = "https://nodes.wavesnodes.com"
    chain = "mainnet"

    pw.setNode(node=node, chain=chain)``` 

as you suggested, took care of the issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this segment of code is redundant:

```
node = "https://nodes.wavesnodes.com"
chain = "mainnet"

pw.setNode(node=node, chain=chain)
```

Refactoring without it resolved the issue.